# Hibernate is not working in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, swap, hibernate

`sudo systemctl hibernate` is not working. When I issue the command, it seems like hibernating. But open applications are lost after hibernate.

```
fazim@fazim-UX410UQK:~$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7857         985        5960         335         911        6363
Swap:          7812           0        7812
```

Swap is configured and on.

Answer (score 0):

Your swap size probably needs to be larger than your memory size.

Currently you have 7,857 MB of RAM but only 7,812 of SWAP.

To fine-tune the swap partition size first check:

```
$ cat /sys/power/image_size
3153907712
```

Then review the [ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Hibernation) article on hibernation. In the article it states hibernation should work if SWAP is 2/5th the size of RAM but your system might be unique in that respect.

Of course there could simply be a bug with your hibernation process as well. The [Ubuntu Handbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/10/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-17-10/) says hibernation is disabled by default because it doesn't work in some machines.

For myself I always use `suspend` and have never bothered with `hibernate`.